# how to change the size of a commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I have the following diagram, but I would like to make its length a bit shorter. I tried to use \Scale, but did not work. Any advice would be useful.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={-latex}]
     \cdots\arrow{r}
        &A
        \arrow{rr}{d}
        \arrow{dr}{g}
            &
            &B
            \arrow{dr}{g}
            \arrow{rr}{d}
            &
            &C
            \arrow{r}
            \arrow{dr}{}
            &\cdots\\
            D
            \arrow{ur}{} 
            &
            &E
            \arrow{ur}{f}
            \arrow[dashed]{ll}
            &
            &F
            \arrow[dashed]{ll}
            \arrow{ur}{f}
            &
            &G
            \arrow[dashed]{ll}
            \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Act on `column sep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
\cdots\arrow[r]
  &A
  \arrow[rr,"d"]
  \arrow[dr,"g"]
  &&B
  \arrow[dr,"g"]
  \arrow[rr,"d"]
  &&C
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[dr]
  &\cdots\\
D\arrow[ur] 
  &&E
  \arrow[ur,"f"]
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  &&F
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  \arrow[ur,"f"]
  &&G
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, but I can't stand the `-latex` arrow tips. `;-)` If you want them, change the options to

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em,arrows=-latex]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tested again. If we omit the `equation*` then it still works. Maybe something else caused the error. (I will delete the previous comment so that it will not mislead others. Thanks for your replying!)